# Remove data from 2 tables simultaneously

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-delete

I have the table `products` and the table `product_comments` (relationship with the table `products`: `product_id`). Now I would need to remove some products from table `products` and if this product has some records in the table `product_comments`, remove also those ones.

Is possible something like that do in PhpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
delete p, c 
from products p
left outer join product_comments c on c.product_id = p.product_id
where p.product_id = 1
```

### [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69d8b/1)